# Gnus Inbox display read and unread emails

Tags: gnus

I set the `.gnus` as

```
;;; package --- gnus
;;;
;;;
(setq user-mail-address "abst.proc.do@qq.com"
      user-full-name "abst.proc.do")

(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "qq.com"
               (nnimap-address "imap.qq.com")  
               (nnimap-server-port 993)
               (nnimap-stream ssl)))

(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.qq.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 465
      smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl
      gnus-ignored-newsgroups "^to\\.\\|^[0-9. ]+\\( \\|$\\)\\|^[\"]\"[#'()]")
```

After run M-x gnus and `L` gnus-group-list-all-group

```
       0: Deleted Messages
       0: Drafts
       1:*INBOX
       0: Junk
       0: Sent Messages
 U     *: nndraft:drafts
       1:*nnfolder+archive:sent.2020-02
```

However, if enter Inbox, it display just the one new email.

```
 R. [   5: -> abst.proc.do        ] Re: Group Buffer
```

How could I set `Inbox` to display all the emails both read and unread.

Add `(dispaly . all)` to group parameters for "inbox" as:

```
((modseq)
 (uidvalidity . "1579733041")
 (display . all)
 (active 1 . 60)
 (permanent-flags %* %Answered %Flagged %Deleted %Draft %Seen))
```

but it still display only the unread mails.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me. Which version of Emacs/Gnus?

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11) of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian @rpluim

Comment: Use L in Group buffer to list all folder and select a folder without unread message, then gnus will display all old messages of that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility of articles in a group is controlled by its group parameters. You can use <kbd>G p</kbd> or <kbd>G c</kbd> when on the group in the *Group* buffer to change them. In this case you'd want something like

```
((display . all))
```

See the [Group Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Group-Parameters.html#Group-Parameters) for more details.

Comment: I appended `(display . all)` to group parameter but still only display unread mails. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a clumsy distinction between "read" and "ancient" articles denoted "R" and "O" respectively.  OP's report that

```
 R. [   5: -> abst.proc.do        ] Re: Group Buffer
```

appears suggests he is indeed getting read articles *viz.* the `R` mark.  He could try `/o` to try to pull in the other 60 messages which might have the `O` mark.

I have never had to specially configure Gnus to get "ancient" articles to display, so something is definitely awry.

Comment: I simply want it display all the emails in the INBOX.

Comment: I know, Gnus makes simple things hard, and hard things possible.

Answer (score 0):

Type `G-c` over the folder and search for `Permanently visible'`. Tick the checkbox next to that and press `[done]`.